# Why does validation break in this ViewModel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

Not sure if this should work but it doesn't. Can anyone explain why it doesn't?
Take a stock standard MVC 3 internet template (forms authentication) and replace the RegisterModel with a RegisterViewModel :

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel registerModel { get; set; }        
}
```

Now change the Register view to reference the @model MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterViewModel and all the controls eg: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.registerModel.UserName).

You will notice that the validation attributes on the Register Model breaks. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you still need to have @Html.ValidationFor(m=>m.registerModel.UserName) ?

Comment: How else would you show the validators?

Comment: The Required validators still work but the Compare validator on the ConfirmPassword breaks.

Comment: Not reproducable for me. I got correct validation client and server side. (In `AccountController` the `Register` post action has to take a `RegisterViewModel` as paramater of course. If not, it leads to an exception.)

Comment: Slauma, yes, the controller, the Register action takes a RegisterViewModel Type. I am using MVC 3 and have unobtrusive validation and ClientValidation set to true in the webconfig. I get the error on ALL brand new projects. I dont understand why you are not getting it. Have you specifically checked the Compare Validator on the RegisterModel?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the inline declaration of "Password" in the compare attribute is having trouble with the nested object.

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

If it helps, you can just use inheritance instead (confirmed this works):

```
public class RegisterViewModel : RegisterModel
{
}
```

[image]

Comment: Terry, I tried your suggestion. The Compare validator is still firing when it shouldn't. Please retest and post a comment.

Comment: Hi Terry - interesting, but you are passing in the RegisterModel to the controller and not the ViewModel.

Comment: @Greg You're right sorry.  Still works though, I updated with the new screenshot.

Comment: - Thanks for checking that. One last question, is UnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled and ClientValidationEnabled settings in your web config set to true? (appSettings). If so, could you send me a copy of your project so I can try and track down the differences. Thanks

Comment: Hi Terry - I found the issue. Its a bug in the jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js script. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665793/jquery-unobtrusive-validate-equalto-fails-with-compare-attribute

Comment: I hate unobtrusive validation, don't use it in my own projects

Comment: Well its kinda cool when it works...but version 8.1 doesn't (in certain circumstances) and I cant find a version that does. MS being MS, they are not telling anyone whether its fixed or not and which version has the fix. The problem here IMO is MS, not the technology. So the reason you weren't getting errors is because your validation weren't firing client side?